# Why does "touch -a" also set the ctime?

Tags: files, filesystems, timestamps, coreutils

Is it touch(1) from coreutils-8.4-37.el6.x86_64 or my brain which is broken?

```
$ touch abc
$ LANG=C stat abc
  File: `abc'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 10485773    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (3060399/ nodakai)   Gid: (  418/   quant)
Access: 2016-10-14 18:42:06.189751847 +0800
Modify: 2016-10-14 18:42:06.189751847 +0800
Change: 2016-10-14 18:42:06.189751847 +0800
$ touch -a abc
$ LANG=C stat abc
  File: `abc'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: fd04h/64772d    Inode: 10485773    Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: (3060399/ nodakai)   Gid: (  418/   quant)
Access: 2016-10-14 18:42:17.374235446 +0800
Modify: 2016-10-14 18:42:06.189751847 +0800
Change: 2016-10-14 18:42:17.374235446 +0800
$ touch --help | grep 'access time'
  -a                     change only the access time
```

As you see, it was not only atime but also ctime which was updated by `touch -a` !?!?

The filesystem is ext4 over LVM if that makes any differences.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`touch`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/touch.html) is specified as changing file access and modification times; changing the change time is a side-effect of the change to the file's metadata, and `touch` doesn't have any control over that (see also the [`futimens()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/futimens.html) and [`utimensat()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utimensat.html) functions used by `touch`).

`-a` and `-m` are understood in this context: by default `touch` changes both access and modification times (and the system updates the change time); with `-a`, it only changes the access time, with `-m`, it only changes the modification time.

You can see the difference if you specify a time other than the current time: the access and/or modification times will be changed to the value you specify, but the change time will be updated to the current time.

Comment: Good to know ctime isn't supposed to be assigned an arbitrary date... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4537291/setting-creation-or-change-timestamps