# When are files from /tmp deleted?

Tags: linux, rhel, tmp

I'd like to investigate when files in /tmp get removed. I run CentOS 7. Policy regarding deleting files from that directory is governed [as follows](https://serverfault.com/a/377349):

> RHEL7 and RedHat-like with systemd it's configured in
>   /usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/tmp.conf, called by systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service)

I guess that three-year-old files are old enough to be deleted. So I set access time this way

```
find  /tmp/payaramicro*tmp -exec touch -m -a -t 201512180130.09 {} \;
```

However, when I run `systemd-tmpfiles --clean` those files won't get deleted. Why? Perhaps it has something to do with their dates as `stat some-file` shows today's date in one of its lines in output:

> Access: 2015-12-18 01:30:09.000000000 +0100
>   Modify: 2015-12-18 01:30:09.000000000 +0100
>   Change: 2018-04-18 12:20:54.095962410 +0200

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `systemd-tmpfiles --clean` considers change times too. You can see this by running it with debug logs enabled:

```
SYSTEMD_LOG_LEVEL=debug systemd-tmpfiles --clean
```

You’ll see it mentioning that the change time is too new.

Comment: Thanks, that's it. On a side note, how do change file dates so that the file would be available for `systemd-tmpfiles --clean`?

Comment: [You can’t control the change time](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316387/86440) (other than by changing your system’s notion of the current time).