# Explain to a beginner the meaning of -mtime in simple human language

Tags: ubuntu, timestamps, file-metadata

Of course, I read the meager lines from the manual. I'm still interested in the specifics.
For example, the `stat / some_files`  command
print this:

```
access 2024 (now)
modified 2022
changeded 2023
created 2023
```

This is, for example, a certain program component, driver, library, script, and so on.
I'm interested in what does modified in 2022 mean?
Does this mean that after downloading the package, unpacking into the appropriate directories / writing to disk occurred at exactly this date / time? And what in this case will “created” mean a year later?

Comment: Is that dash in "-mtime" in the subject a typo, or did you mean to signify something with it? `-mtime` is a condition predicate in `find`, but you seem to be asking about the different timestamps.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you’ve seen the basics:

- access time reflects the latest access to the file (with varying granularity on `relatime` file systems, or not at all if `noatime` is used)
- modification time reflects the latest modification of the contents of the file
- change time reflects the latest modification of the file’s metadata
- creation time reflects the time at which the file was created in the file system

There’s an additional subtlety which is important in your case: [access and modification times](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/316387/86440) can be changed, whereas change and creation times are set by the file system. In particular, modification times are commonly preserved in archives, and restored when archives are extracted. So if you install for example a distribution package, the files it contains will have a creation timestamp corresponding to the time at which the package was installed (the files were created *on your system*), but a modification timestamp corresponding to the timestamp stored in their archive, which is usually the time at which the package was built.

As a result of this, access times and modification times are ambiguous: they are *supposed* to reflect specific events in a file’s life, but they can skip updates (for access time) or be updated independently of the specific events. They can be set to arbitrary values so there isn’t even a guaranteed chronological order.

Thus a file installed in 2023 from a package built in 2022, and last accessed in 2024, will initially have creation (if supported by the file system) and last change timestamps in 2023, a modification timestamp in 2022, and a last access timestamp in 2024. Aside from the creation timestamp, all the other timestamps can be updated by anyone with write permission on the file and/or containing directory.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152279/discussion-on-answer-by-stephen-kitt-explain-to-a-beginner-the-meaning-of-mtime); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

When software is packaged for distribution (in Linux, often in `*.rpm` or `*.deb` packages, but also any archive files like `*.tar.gz` or `*.zip`), these packaging methods will generally preserve the modification time of the files in the originating system, and reproduce these original modification timestamps on installation/unarchiving.

Sometimes, the person or organization packaging the software for distribution will adjust the modification timestamps of all files belonging to a particular release of the software to some known value, to simplify the identification of file versions in bug reports, or just to reflect the release date of that specific release.

You might expect that the *creation* timestamp would be preserved too, but the creation time is not a mandatory part of POSIX specifications: some Unix filesystems don't track file creation times at all, and so preserving the modification time of the file contents was considered the most important one in file archiving programs.

```
access 2024 (now)
modified 2022
changed 2023
created 2023
```

If this file belongs to a software package, I would expect that the file was either last modified by the developer or packaged for release in 2022, and the modification time reflects that.

It was installed on your system in 2023 (as indicated by the creation time and metadata change time). At that point, the installation process reproduced the origin system's modification time of 2022 for this file on your system, although strictly speaking this file did not exist on your system in 2022.

Since modification time < creation time, the contents of this file were created on some other system and then transferred to yours.

As the creation time is essentially equal to metadata change time and the modification time is less than or equal to creation time, we can see the file and its metadata (ownership, permissions, attributes) has apparently not been modified in any way since it was installed to your system.